# The Canvas Object in list when called, gets an increased speed than the previous one, even without any such call (to increase speed)

Tags: python, tkinter

So, this is an edited question (although it's not related to the previous one), well coming back to the topic, here's, my code:

```py
# Importing the required Modules
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as Alert
import numpy # ? Use import random if numpy not availale
import math

class Set_Game:
    
    # Defining the __init__ function of the class
    def __init__(self, Main_Frame):
        
        self.Start_Game()
        
        # Creating empty arrays for Enemies and Bullets
        self.Missiles = []
        self.Enemies = []
        
        # Setting a number of Enemies
        self.Number_Of_Enemies = 5
        
        # Setting the enemies' speed
        self.Enemies_Speed = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
        
        self.Missile_Speed = -3
        
        self.Set_Enemies()
        self.Move_Enemies()
        
        Window.after(3000, self.Move_Enemy_Down)
    
    def Move_Enemies(self):
        
        for Enemy in self.Enemies:
            
            x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = Can.coords(self.Enemies[self.Enemies.index(Enemy)])
            
            if x3 > 1000 or x1 < 0:
                self.Enemies_Speed[self.Enemies.index(Enemy)] = -self.Enemies_Speed[self.Enemies.index(Enemy)]
            
            Can.move(self.Enemies[self.Enemies.index(Enemy)], self.Enemies_Speed[self.Enemies.index(Enemy)], 0) 
            
            if y2 > 630:
                Alert.showinfo("Space Shooter", "The Game is Over!")
                Can.delete("all")
                return
            
        Window.after(18, self.Move_Enemies)
    
    # Set the Initial Position of Enemies    
    def Set_Enemies(self):
        for Enemy in range(self.Number_Of_Enemies):
            x = numpy.random.randint(960) # ? Use x = random.randint(0, 960) if numpy not available
            y = numpy.random.randint(20, 270) # ? Use y = random.randint(20, 270) if numpy not available
            Enemy = Can.create_polygon([x, y, x + 20, y + 20, x + 40, y], outline = "Red", fill = "Red")
            self.Enemies.append(Enemy)
        
    # Start the Game
    def Start_Game(self):
        # Placing the Widgets
        Can.pack()

        # Binding the Keys to move the Player
        Window.bind("<Key>", self.Move_Player)

    def Move_Player(self, event):
        Direction = event.keysym
        
        # Checking if the Left Arroe button id clicked
        if Direction == "Left":
            
            # Moving the Player to Left Direction
            Can.move(Player, -10, 0)
            
        # Checking if the Right Arroe button id clicked
        elif Direction == "Right":
            
            # Moving the Player to Left Direction
            Can.move(Player, 10, 0)
        
        elif Direction == "Up":
            
            self.Fire()    
            
    def Move_Enemy_Down(self):
    
        for Enemy in self.Enemies:
            Can.move(Enemy, 0, 30)
            
        Window.after(3000, self.Move_Enemy_Down)

    def Fire(self):
        
        x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = Can.coords(Player)
        
        Missile = Can.create_oval(x2 - 3, y2 - 6, x2 + 3, y2, outline = "Yellow", fill = "Yellow")
        self.Missiles.append(Missile)
        
        self.Move_Missile()
        
    def Move_Missile(self):
            
        for Missile in self.Missiles:
            
            Can.move(Missile, 0, self.Missile_Speed)
            
            Mx1, My1, Mx2, My2 = Can.coords(Missile)
            
            if My1 < 0:
                Can.delete(Missile)
                self.Missiles.pop(self.Missiles.index(Missile))
            
            for Enemy in self.Enemies:
                Ex1, Ey1, Ex2, Ey2, Ex3, Ey3 = Can.coords(Enemy) 
                
                if My1 >= Ey1 and My1 <= Ey3 or My1 >= Ey2 and My1 <= Ey3:
                    if Mx1 >= Ex1 and Mx1 <= Ex3 or Mx2 >= Ex1 and Mx2 >= Ex3:
                        Can.delete(Missile)
                        self.Missiles.pop(self.Missiles.index(Missile))
                        
                        Can.delete(Enemy)
                        self.Enemies.pop(self.Enemies.index(Enemy))
                        self.Enemies_Speed.pop(self.Enemies.index(Enemy))   # ValueError: (1-5) is not in list
            
        Window.after(18, self.Move_Missile)
    
# Initializing Game Window
Window = Tk()
Window.title("Space Shooter")

# Defining the Game Canvas
Can = Canvas(Window, background = "Black", height = 630, width = 1000)
Player = Can.create_polygon(280, 620, 300, 600, 320, 620, fill = "Blue", outline = "Blue")

# Calling the Set_Game Class
Game = Set_Game(Window)

# Adding Mainloop
Window.mainloop()
```

Now I have a  of problems here, the speed of the missile gets increased each time than the previous one, after firing nearly 20 bullets, it catches in insane speed. I don't know why it's happening, but I have a suspect in the

```py
for Missile in self.Missiles:
```

line.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You call `self.Start_Game` (which actually does nothing) after deleting all items in canvas.  You should call `self.Start_Game()` instead.  However you should not call the two `Window.after(...)` when `self.Start_Game()` is called in this situation.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much! I don't know how... Well, I was so tensed in the code that I forgot the parenthesis after the function call. It didn't even have me an error. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Because it's not an error. Dot operator calls `__getitem__`. Parentheses execute `__call__`. Retrieving a bound function is a perfectly legal operation. You aren't obligated to call it afterwards

Comment: I didn't get it, well...

Comment: I just wanted to know the reason and solution for the insane speed of the missile, I found a solution for that second reason.